# How to add tooltip to an svg graphics element using javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, canvas, tooltip

I have a chart of d3.parcoords and want to add tooltip for first axis of chart. I'm retrieving first axis DOM element and adding title property to it to make it as its tooltip. No success!

**Image of UI**

[image: Here is the UI]

**Here is code:**

```
    var segmentAxis = self.pcz.svg.selectAll(".dimension .axis")[0][0];

    segmentAxis.title="Tooltip";
```

Comment: In SVG a tooltip is a child element, not an attribute.

Comment: @RobertLongson, Can you please help me to do that in javascript. I'm very close but not succeeded yet!

Comment: You know how to create an element? To give it text content? To add it as a child of another element? Which of the above are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robert said, SVG doesn't use `title` attributes. It has a `<title>` element instead.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#struct-DescriptionAndTitleElements

If you want to add a tooltip to an SVG group, you'll need to create a `<title>` element for your group.

```
<g>
  <title>Your tooltip here</title>
  ... other elements...
</g>
```

The D3 code will look something like this:

```
d3.selectAll('.dimension .axis')[0].append("svg:title").text("Your tooltip here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with the help of Paul LeBeau answer:

**Here is the screen-shot**
[image: Here is the UI of solution]

**Here is the Code:**

```
        var toolTip=d3.select("#dvAllProfiles").select("svg")
        .append("svg:title")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text("Test Tooltip");

        self.pcz.svg.selectAll(".dimension").data([0]).selectAll(".tick")
        .selectAll("*")
        .style("font-size", "12px").style("transform", "rotate(340deg)")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            return toolTip.style("visibility", "visible").style("top", event.pageY+"px").style("left",event.pageX+"px").text(d);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
            return toolTip.style("visibility", "hidden")  
        });
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to hide and show the tooltip yourself. See: https://jsfiddle.net/6f9wg7ov/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, I have to show tooltip just for the values of left-most axis. Moreover, I have to show their full text in tooltip. How to set all of this without working with mouseover and mouseleave events?